# Incorrect breakers in Thomas & Betts Panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, code-compliance

I have a Thomas & Betts panel with 40 slots and was going about trying map out the circuits when I noticed a few suspect breakers. The entire right side of the panel contains only T&B (type TB) breakers which I think are fine, but the left side has a mix (some T&B, but a few I suspect shouldn't be there).

I don't want to spend money for no reason but my instincts tell me at least some of these breakers should be replaced (for safety and/or code compliance?), which is why I'm posting here to see if I'm right and should fork out the ~$60 to replace them or maybe worrying for no reason and can keep my cash in my pocket.

Based on some other posts I've found here, I *think* I know what to replace them with. But, again, looking for feedback.

Here's what I'm thinking, and THANKS in advance!
-Jwawa

P.S. I can post a picture of the entire breaker panel, but felt like I was pushing it already with too many pics.

[image: TBB20(40-40)C Service Panel]

- Slot 3:
  [image: GE 20A HACR Type RT-692 TYPE THQL]

  - Currently: GE 20A HACR Type RT-692 TYPE THQL
  - Replace with: Eaton CL120 or CL220
- Slots 4, 9, and 10:
  [image: Eaton 20A HACR Type C120 Type BR120]

  - Currently: Eaton 20A HACR Type C120 Type BR120
  - Replace with: Eaton CL120 or CL220
- Slot 11:
  [image: Challenger 20A HACR Type C120]

  - Currently: Challenger 20A HACR Type C120
  - Replace with: Eaton CL120 or CL220
- Slot 13-14:
  [image: Cutler-Hammer BR230]

  - Currently: Cutler-Hammer Type BR230
  - Replace with Eaton CL230 Common Trip
- Slot 19-20:
  [image: Unbranded 230]

  - Currently: Unbranded "E-45310" GFCI 2-pole 2x30A. This was for a hot tub which we removed when we moved in 20+ years ago.
  - This circuit is currently not in use, so no need to find a replacement. Replace with Filler plates?